# How to solve $x^3-3x= \sqrt 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^3-3x= \sqrt 3$$

I have tried solving above equation using trial error method with many alternatives. I reached just near in decimal number. Actually, I need the radical exact notation, which will be used for finding chords. Based on other items, value of $x$ depends, probably, on square root of 2, 3, 6 and/or 9.

Thanks in advance for solution of $x$.

Comment: cubic equations have solutions , like quadratic do , so maybe just use that

Comment: Closed formulas can be found, eg, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).  "Cardano's method" is the best thing to search for.

Comment: get contemporary, get recent https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-3x-%E2%88%9A3%3D%3D0

Comment: Well, this _does_ have three real roots, but I think you'll find they're not as simple as you may be thinking they are...

Comment: There is no solution in terms of **real** radicals.

Answer (score 10):

Set $x=2z$. The equation becomes:
$$ 4z^3-3z = \cos\frac{\pi}{6}, $$
but since [$4z^3-3z=T_3(z)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html), the solutions to the above equation are given by $\left\{\cos\frac{\pi}{18},\cos\frac{13\pi}{18},\cos\frac{25\pi}{18}\right\}$ and $$x\in\left\{2\cos\frac{\pi}{18},2\cos\frac{13\pi}{18},2\cos\frac{25\pi}{18}\right\}.$$
Since for every $n\geq 2$ we have that $\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}$, the above numbers are algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $6$. The [cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) leads to the solution:
$$ 2\cos\frac{\pi}{18} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{2}}.$$